# What does the phrase "lowest rated in history" mean?

Tags: ambiguity, trumpism, disambiguation

Does it mean the **RATINGS** or **QUALITY** being the lowest ever?

Edit: Some context here - two days after the show aired, Trump tweeted -

> Lowest rated Oscars in HISTORY. Problem is, we don’t have Stars anymore - except your President (just kidding, of course)!

Comment: Can we have more context (sentences either side if possible, and certainly a full sentence) please.

Comment: Who knows what the oracle means when he tweets his utterances

Comment: Whatever he means, he isn't praising the ceremony,

Comment: These gems from Mr Trump's Tweet box should be called 'Treets'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth See my edit.

Comment: Entirely opinion based. There is no linguistic way to tell what someone was thinking, or what they intended to convey, with an ambiguous sentence.

Comment: Wait... it says 'Lowest rated...' and you're wondering whether it's talking about ratings or something else?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, that's what I want to know.

Comment: @Danny But it _says_ 'rated'. Why would you think it's anything else?

Comment: @Mitch Because according to Oxford Dictionary, as a verb 'rate' can mean 'Consider to be of a certain quality or standard', 'Be regarded in a specified way' or 'Be worthy of; merit' - anything but 'ratings'. May be a slip through the net by Oxford.

Comment: @NigelJ - They're called "twits".

Comment: @Danny So then you're done, it's both right? It's a rating of quality.

Answer (score 2):

Since Trump, reputedly, gets much of his information from Fox News, we can look at their comments, e.g. from
http://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/2018/03/06/oscars-ratings-are-down-and-abcs-lack-control-over-academy-may-be-to-blame.html

we see

> The politically charged 2018 Academy Awards were down 20 percent in the ratings compared to the 2017 numbers, averaging 26.5 million viewers.

Almost certainly, he means viewing numbers.